# Changing values from config file after building the reactApp

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, config.json

Is it possible to give parameters using .config file to reactApp after running `npm run build` I am fetching data thorugh a url in reactApp. I need to deploy only the built file.

After giving `npm run build`, can't I change the values through config file like in Java. Or else re-building the app is the only solution?

Answer (score 0):

process.env.SOME_VARIABLE is used to provide an environment variable. You can initialize this variable with build app command. Check more on create-react-app repo docs

Comment: I am asking for parameters to be used within .js files. Not for environment variables.

Comment: When you build a react app process.env.NODE_ENV has value "production" and in development, it has value 'development' (automatic set by create-react-app) when you export a config file you can check its production/developm ent and export a file as per need.  I don't know a better way to inject different config in production.